# Ruby On Rails get from the tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am completely newbish in ruby, but i figured out how to create databases. 
I did this

```
rails generate scaffold MYTABLENAME
```

and in the db/migrate i edited the file so it had my columns etc.

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :username
      t.string :password
      t.string :email
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

This is correct right?

Now i got this output:

```
  invoke  active_record
  create    db/migrate/20130325134909_create_posts.rb
  create    app/models/post.rb
  invoke    test_unit
  create      test/unit/post_test.rb
  create      test/fixtures/posts.yml
  invoke  resource_route
   route    resources :posts
  invoke  scaffold_controller
  create    app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
  invoke    erb
  create      app/views/posts
  create      app/views/posts/index.html.erb
  create      app/views/posts/edit.html.erb
  create      app/views/posts/show.html.erb
  create      app/views/posts/new.html.erb
  create      app/views/posts/_form.html.erb
  invoke    test_unit
  create      test/functional/posts_controller_test.rb
  invoke    helper
  create      app/helpers/posts_helper.rb
  invoke      test_unit
  create        test/unit/helpers/posts_helper_test.rb
  invoke  assets
  invoke    coffee
  create      app/assets/javascripts/posts.js.coffee
  invoke    scss
  create      app/assets/stylesheets/posts.css.scss
  invoke  scss
  create    app/assets/stylesheets/scaffolds.css.scss
   invoke  active_record
  create    db/migrate/20130325134909_create_posts.rb
  create    app/models/post.rb
  invoke    test_unit
  create      test/unit/post_test.rb
  create      test/fixtures/posts.yml
  invoke  resource_route
   route    resources :posts
  invoke  scaffold_controller
  create    app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
  invoke    erb
  create      app/views/posts
  create      app/views/posts/index.html.erb
  create      app/views/posts/edit.html.erb
  create      app/views/posts/show.html.erb
  create      app/views/posts/new.html.erb
  create      app/views/posts/_form.html.erb
  invoke    test_unit
  create      test/functional/posts_controller_test.rb
  invoke    helper
  create      app/helpers/posts_helper.rb
  invoke      test_unit
  create        test/unit/helpers/posts_helper_test.rb
  invoke  assets
  invoke    coffee
  create      app/assets/javascripts/posts.js.coffee
  invoke    scss
  create      app/assets/stylesheets/posts.css.scss
  invoke  scss
  create    app/assets/stylesheets/scaffolds.css.scss
```

---

It also sounds good. But why does it automaticly insert

```
  app/views/posts/index.html.erb
  app/views/posts/edit.html.erb
  app/views/posts/show.html.erb
  app/views/posts/new.html.erb
  app/views/posts/_form.html.erb
```

and so on? Is it standard, if so - why? Please explain.

And the other question is: 
In my home controller (as standard ../home/index) i tried to create an user into my new fresh database, but it tells me that uninitialized constant HomeController::Users - why?

Here is my code:

```
 class HomeController < ApplicationController
     def index
      #@users = User.all
        o = Users.new
        o.username = "Jesper"
        o.save
     end
 end
```

Comment: Hmm you may want to check out one of the many great Beginners tutorials for Rails. http://railsforzombies.org/ http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

Comment: Your code has lots of problems. First of all: you didn't create the database yet. You created a so-called scaffolding for your app, but the database hasn't been created yet. The problem with your controller is that you should use `User` instead of `Users`. Please follow a beginners tutorial. If you are stuck with that, use Google. Still stuck? Ask a specific question here.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#getting-up-and-running-quickly-with-scaffolding will answer your first question. You can find the answer to the second question on the same website :)

Comment: I already have readed tutorials, but cannot find any usefull for databases. I have also done railsforzombies.

Comment: I did figure it out to print out something, great. But how can i "create" databases manually instead of scaffolding?

Comment: By using [migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html). After creating a migration you have to run `rake db:migrate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to generate a model you should have done:

```
rails generate model MYTABLENAME username:string password:string email:string
```

Scaffolding generate everything from the model to the view (with the default CRUD operations). You should read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html. This guide will cover all the basics.

Answer (score -1):

Models name must be in singular

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

     def index
      #@users = User.all
        o = User.new
        o.username = "Jesper"
        o.save
     end
 end
```

**User instead of Users**